# Wordpress - Only allow page to be shown after form is submitted

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I have two pages in a WordPress installation - one with a MailChimp signup form, and then a second page which shows a thank you message where the user is sent after completing the MailChimp signup form.

Right now, the thank you page is just a regular WordPress page. While there are no links to it in the navigation, it is possible to visit the page directly if you have the URL.

However, I need to make this page so that it cannot be accessed unless the signup form was submitted, and I also need to make sure that the page cannot be refreshed. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top of your page.

The form action on the first page must be the 'thank you' page.

```
<from method="POST" action="page2.php">
Your form input.
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo('You hacker!');
}else{
    // Rest of the page
?>
    <html> etc.
    thank you bla bla....
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the referrer from the $_SERVER variable.

In your thank-you page, put something like this

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'mailchimp_host') {
  echo 'Thank - you ';
  ....
}
else {
  echo "Not authorized to view this page";
}
```

Substituite mailchimp_host with the real hostname of the mailchimp server that is doing the subscription of the user. See you log files!